# How can I set the height of a td using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `table` with a `td` as follows:

```
<td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2014-03-26">
```

I want to set the height of the `td` to 144px. I tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
$('.fc-day').attr('height', 144);
```

Comment: what you just use `css` ? `$('.fc-day').css('height', 144+'px');`

Comment: Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3mSnP/)

Comment: In what browser or version of jQuery does this not work?

Comment: @Arvie If one of the answers helped you solve the problem, please choose it as the solution.

Answer (score 5):

Using the .attr() method will set the attribute but not the css. You better use the .height() method instead of the .attr() or .css() methods as it will take care of everything and also is the shortest and most readable option:

```
$('.fc-day').height(144); // Pixels are the default
```

You can pass it a sting to specify a unit:

```
$('.fc-day').height("144px"); 
$('.fc-day').height("50%");
```

You can read more about it here:
https://api.jquery.com/height/

**Edit:** Another benefit of using the .height() method over .css() is that you don't have to deal with whether the box-sizing property was set for the element and the cross-browser support issues that can come up when using it. When using the .height() method it will set the content height regardless of the value set for the box-sizing property and the browser support for it, It's much more intuitive.

If you do want to set the CSS height directly (affected by the box-sizing property) you can use the .css() method (as noted by stigok in his answer):

```
$('.fc-day').css('height', '144px');
```

but usually .height() would be what you want...

Comment: I am not aware of cross-browser issues related to CSS height. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Mostly the fact that if you're setting the height of a box via the .css() method you'll have to consider the box-sizing property (which on some browsers isn't supported) and if you're using the .height() method then it will set the content height regardless of the value set for the box-sizing property and the browser support for it, It's much more intuitive. Calling it cross-browser issues might be too general, I'll edited that, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the CSS of the `<td>` instead.

```
$('.fc-day').css('height', '144px');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.fc-day').attr('height', '144px');` should work. You forgot the PX

Comment: I would recommend using .css() or .height() instead.

Comment: Probably better indeed, I was just taking this men's code and telling the mistake.

Comment: Ok. But it doesn't even require px.